# How to change the background of the image after capturing from camera using imagepicker?

Tags: flutter

I am creating new app with image capture. For example, if i capture a person with green background image, after capture i need to remove the green background and add another background image.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the same way as on other platform. You can think of it like this.

1. replace the green pixel with any colour with alpha (opacity) = 0.
2. put the image on top of your background photo.